# Is it possible to extend an inline partial in handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

I have the following code, and I'm trying to extend an inline partial, but am receiving the following error: `Error: missing partial: 'page'`

Here's the inline partial:

```
{{#*inline "page"}}
  {{#block "title"}}Example - {{/block}}
{{/inline}}
```

Here's my attempt to use it:

```
{{#*inline "page"}}
  <section>
    {{#block "title"}}Example - {{/block}}
  </section>
{{/inline}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.

Here's the syntax:

```
{{#*inline "page"}}
  <section>{{> @partial-block }}</section>
{{/inline}}
```

and then using page like this:

```
{{#>page}}
  {{> cover}}
{{/page}}
```

works!